# ipython notebook not finding mathplotlib module

Tags: macos, anaconda

This is what I see when I try to import mathplotlib

```
In [11]:

import numpy as np
import mathplotlib.pyplot as plt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d33586aa69ae> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import mathplotlib as plt

ImportError: No module named mathplotlib
```

I am not sure it is relevant but in other forums people talk about their .bashrc files.

```
Lindas-iMac:~ iMacLinda$ cat .bashrc

export PATH="/Users/iMacLinda/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Matplotlib is definitely installed

```
Lindas-iMac:~ iMacLinda$ conda list | grep matplo
matplotlib                1.4.3               np110py27_3
```

I have done the following updates

```
conda update ipython 
conda update ipython-notebook 
conda updata ipython-qtconsole
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: It's spelled ``matplotlib`` not ``mathplotlib``. Give that a try :)

Answer (score 0):

sorry the problem was a typo. It should be matplotlib and not mathplotlib